# Authentication between apps on host MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

Please help me to do this way
I have 2 MVC3 apps with form authentication. The URL like this
http://localhost/app1
http://localhost/app2
When I signed in/out to one of the app with same user information, another app has the same cookies and login session. But I don't want it that way. I want to separate login info among 2 apps.
Please help.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **app1** edit your web.config. Give the authentication tag a unique "name" attribute.

```
<forms name="App1">
```

...and do the same in **app2**.

```
<forms name="App2">
```

MSDN has some related information about sharing tickets across applications  [[link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx).

Comment: Actually, you should add name attribute in the <forms> tag, in child level. Many thanks.

Comment: @akari Ha, noob mistake by me. I provided the link and was incapable of copy and pasting! Will update for future viewers...